# Is there a formula to setup the smallest rectangle enclosing a PSTricks grid and its labels?

Tags: pstricks

I want to minimize the size of the red rectangle enclosing a PSTricks grid and its labels. How to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=5pt}
\psset{style=gridstyle}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\psframebox[linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=red,framesep=5.5pt]{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.2](1.5,1.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not possible; the labels with `showgrid` are written on PostScript level. With `\psaxes` you can write it into a box and then measure width and height.

Comment: How to make `\psgrid` and `\psaxes` exactly get overlapped one on the other? If you can do that, it is very helpful to measure the `\psgrid` box in advance.